# What was the purpose of the hanging chair?

Tags: event-horizon

The crew of the Louis & Clark all sat at stations in regular chairs, but Captain Miller had a swinging hanging chair that spun around. Why does his chair hang and swing? I think the Event Horizon also had one of these chairs in the command center.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely visibility/accessibility. Passengers have to just look ahead while pilot has to look at all the instruments, that might not be just straight in front of him, but also to his sides. Another reason is that the ship will not necessary go straight ahead - it can go sideways for example, like a tugboat, and [since space is an ocean...](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceIsAnOcean)

Comment: Well that would make sense for a swivel chair, but how does hanging it from the ceiling help this? I'm actually imagining some very comical problems should their artificial gravity go down. He's the only person not attached to the floor, hoping it made sense in some way.